# Nested Gridview with subtotal/grandtotal

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm using C# .net 2.0. My code behind dynamically generates a SQL statement that would return something like this in a dataset.

```
Name | Yes | No | NoReply | Group
John |  1  |    |         |  A
Bob  |     |  1 |         |  A
Lee  |  1  |    |         |  B
Harry|     |    |      1  |  C
Liz  |     |  1 |         |  B
```

Currently, I bind the data to a `GridView` to display the result on a page. I'd like to break them up into group and have a subtotal and grandtotal at the bottom of each group. For example:

Group A:

```
Name | Yes | No | NoReply
John    1
Bob           1           
--------------------------
Subtotal 1    1     0
```

Group B:

```
Name | Yes | No | NoReply
Lee     1                
Liz           1          
--------------------------
Subtotal 1    1
```

Group C:

```
Name | Yes | No | NoReply
Harry               1                
--------------------------
Subtotal            1

Grandtotal: sums of yes/no/no reply columns.
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I would suggest is to group the data in SQL as you mentioned above and then use a Repeater control to bind the resulting data.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks, what about subtotal and grandtotal?

Comment: You should compute all the values in the SQL using "Sum" function and use C# code just to bind the data to Repeater.